# No module named '_dbus_bindings' after upgrading to python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, update-manager

After upgrading to python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04, I am no longer able to launch Software Updater.  Running software-properties-gtk gives:

```
$ software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 30, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
```

Both python-dbus and python3-dbus are installed at the newest version (1.2.6-1).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do not change the version of Python that comes installed with Ubuntu. When you did so, you broke your system. Revert to Python 3.6. and it will work again.

Comment: Preventing confusion: Version 1.2.6-1 is the newest version *for Ubuntu 18.04*. Newer releases of Ubuntu have newer versions...but those newer versions are NOT compatible with your 18.04 system, so leave them alone.

Comment: Too bad, was hard enough to get it (mostly) working.  Thanks.